# How to spy on function from another module

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon

I have two functions in one module:

```
export function foo() {
  console.log('foo');
}

export function bar() {
  foo()
}
```

Now I want to test `bar()`, set a [spy](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#sinonspy) on `foo()`  and assert for it to be called. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Just an idea..... What about using aspect oriented programming?

Comment: How do you mean `spy`?

Comment: @Xotic750 actually, I've meant this http://sinonjs.org/docs/#sinonspy

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT/update:** Sorry had bar and foo backwards.
The way the module is currently structured.

When the code is executed, the bar reference inside function bar is resolved against the local implementation. You can't modify that since it's outside of the module code. There's no access to the intervals.

Have you tried using code like this for the test file?

```
let obj = {};
obj.bar = function () {
 this.foo();
}

obj.foo = function() {
 ...
}

export default obj;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the problem is that imported function in my test isn't one called in my module. They are different instances, so it will not give me any result.

Comment: I know the approach that you've suggested in your edited answer, I also know the approach to spy on prototype methods, but I was wandering if there is a way to do it just with functions.